# Flask WTF always fails

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm trying to build a user input form using Flask WTF.

The problem is that when I debug my code, it always fails at

```
  if not form.validate_on_submit():
```

even if I don't have anything to fail, it just go inside that if statement and my submitted data stays in the form rather than going back to index page.

- my server side code

  ```
  @post_user_blueprint.route('/post_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  def post_user():
     form = InputForm(request.form)
     if not form.validate_on_submit():
        return render_template('wtf_input.html', form=form)

     return redirect(url_for('.index'))
  ```
- html (using helper class to macro the input field and error)

  ```
  <form action="/post_user" method='post' name='post_user' enctype=multipart/form-data >

  {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
  {{ form.csrf }}
  {{render_field(form.individual_first_name)}}
  {{render_field(form.individual_last_name)}}

  <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT'/>

  </form>
  ```
- WTF class

  ```
  class InputForm(FlaskForm):

      individual_first_name = StringField("First Name",             
      [validators.InputRequired("Please enter first name")])
      individual_last_name = StringField("Patient Last Name", 
      [validators.InputRequired("Please enter last name")])

       submit = SubmitField("Send")
  ```

Thanks in advance

Comment: WTF has a `form.errors` which you can print in your template (`{{form.errors}}`) that might shed some light on what it is failing the validation on.

Comment: @dcrosta sorry that I didn't mention about helper class, it catches up all the errors for you inside the macro, but even no errors are there , I cannot clear my data after submitting the input form.

Comment: There can be form-wide errors that don't show up as individual field errors, I seem to recall.

Comment: @dcrosta, hm.. never heard of form wide errors but by just looking at it, it  is just too simple to have any errors... but let me check

Comment: @ dcrosta, Thanks bud I figured it out , CSRF token missing omg...

Comment: @ dcrosta, if you can post what you said in comment,  I'll select your answer